# Compare for Priority Queue in JAVA

Tags: java, oop, queue, priority-queue

I'll make it clear right now this is for an assignment in university. I would like advice and answers that will help me learn, not copy and paste. I have an assignment which requires simulating a hospital ER. It is to practice ADT's and the implementation of a Priority Queue. One of the conditions of the assignment states that i need to create a compareTo method which will i guess help priorities the patients coming in the ER and it is determined based on the severity condition. If severity is greater than 17 i must replace it with 17, if severity is smaller than 1 i must replace it with one... I am still confused on this compreTo and how exactly two objects or int's are compared :S.... based on what I have written below, can anyone explain to me how to compare severities?

This is just rough rough rough draft just to get a basic idea, i will have a object called patient which i assume will also have a NAME and CONDITION SEVERITY...

> //Comparator Method...
>
> int severity
>
> if (severity > 17) {
>
> replace severity with 17        if (patient severity > other patient
>   severity) {       return 1        }
>
> else if(patient severity > other patient severity) {        return -1       }
>     else if (patient severity == other patient severity) {      return 0        }
>   }
>
> else if (severity < 1) {
>
> replace severity with 17        if (patient severity > other patient
>   severity) {       return 1        }
>
> else if(patient severity > other patient severity) {        return -1       }
>     else if (patient severity == other patient severity) {      return 0        }
>   }
>
> else {
>
> replace severity with 17        if (patient severity > other patient
>   severity) {       return 1        }
>
> else if(patient severity > other patient severity) {        return -1       }
>     else if (patient severity == other patient severity) {      return 0        }
>   }

basically the question is, what code do you use to compare two objects or two integers that belong to an object. and how do does a comparator work if i have many items to compare within a priority queue. Thanks for all help / input!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say we have a class `Patient` with an int variable `severity`.

The operation 'treat an int as being min if it is below min and max if it is below maxed' is called clamping. It can be useful to make a clamping helper function, like so:

```
public static int clamp(int value, int min, int max)
{
   return value < min ? min : value > max ? max : value;
}

public int compareTo(Parent other)
{
    int clampedSeverity = clamp(this.severity, 1, 17);
    int clampedOtherSeverity = clamp(this.severity, 1, 17);
    //do comparisons
}
```

Now, to make a `PriorityQueue` - the semantics of a `PriorityQueue` are that of a collection which is automatically sorted on any insert such that the highest comparing element (in this case, highest severity) is at the beginning.

So to insert into a `PriorityQueue`, we could have the `PriorityQueue` 'backed' by say an `ArrayList`, and binary search into it using `compareTo` to see if we need to look higher, lower or if we have a match. If we have a match then we can insert right there. If we don't get a match but we've narrowed it down to being more severe than the element below but less than the element above, we can insert it there.

If all inserts keep the `PriorityQueue` sorted, then the most severe patient is always on top.

Answer (score 1):

You should start by writing a method which transforms a raw severity with a "normalized" severity (i.e. a severity between 1 and 17). And then you should compare patients by their normalized secerity:

```
private int normalizedSeverity(int severity) {
    if (severity < 1) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (severity > 17) {
        return 17;
    }
    return severity;
}

public int compare(Patient p1, Patient p2) {
    int severity1 = normalizedSeverity(p1.getSeverity());
    int severity2 = normalizedSeverity(p2.getSeverity());
    return Integer.compare(severity1, severity2);
}
```